# Check if header is present in request with apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I check if a header exist. I dont want to check if the value is different of "" I want to check if it really exist using:

RewriteCond

How can I do that inside htaccess file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a condition like this to know if a header `X-SomeHeader` exists or not:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block if request header X-SomeHeader doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SomeHeader} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: if the header is set and the value is empty I think your solution would fail.

Comment: Yes, this is a check for empty value only.

Comment: So how do I know if the header does not exist. If the header is empty it still exists and your regex would fail.

Comment: Yes, as I said earlier also this check if for empty value. There is no check for existence and I think a empty value header doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that there is nocheck for exitence?

Comment: No I am no aware of any check for existence. If you know then please share

Answer (score 11):

@anhubhava's answer was useful but logic inverted! it should be:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block if request header X-SomeHeader doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SomeHeader} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

or for an opposite example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect foo to bar if request header X-SomeHeader exists
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SomeHeader} !^$
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar [L]
```

Comment: Whether I try this answer or the inverted answer, it doesn't prevent recursion for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
RewriteEngine On

# block if request header X-SomeHeader doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{HTTP:TID} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```