# How to restrict access to origin for CloudFront only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

How to restrict access to origin for Amazon CloudFront only?

[image]

Comment: Depending on your use case, a simple bucket policy could suffice (i.e. only allow the CloudFront distribution to GetObjects)

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5):

Create a Custom Origin Header with a secret value, and add it to the origin configuration in CloudFront.

Modify your origin server configuration to throw an error if a request comes in without this secret value.

This is one of the reasons CloudFront supports custom origin headers.

> If you configure your custom origin to respond to requests only if they include a custom header, you can prevent users from bypassing CloudFront and submitting requests directly to your origin.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html

Comment: You mean something like this in apache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42866572/5002478 ?

Comment: Yes, that looks promising.  The `^$` here looks like an empty string regular expression, so you'd be looking for something more like `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SecretHeader} !^SecretValueGoesHere$` but be sure you test thoroughly.

Comment: You can also use Amazon Web ACL to create a simple rule for this, so you don't have to change the origin server code.

Comment: @Falco the screenshot in the question shows this to be a custom origin, which might be inside AWS and might not be.  What is an "Amazon Web ACL" in this case?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot "Amazon Web ACL" is a service from AWS, where you can create custom rules to filter requests on load-balancers, instances, etc. - So if your Setup is like this: `Cloudfront - AWS Load Balancer - custom origin` - you can create an Web ACL Rule on the Load Balancer, which checks the Header and blocks the request if the header is not present. I'm running a live service exactly with this solution. In this way the secret is only configured in the AWS console for 2 services (cloudfront & Web ACL) and nowhere else.

Comment: @Falco ah, okay, yes... a web ACL in AWS WAF attached to an ALB would work for this.